# roughness texture is missing when I export file fbx

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, .fbx, roughness

I link image texture with roughness and export fbx file, but when I look in 3D view, no roughness appears, only diffuse and normal appear.
1.Why is it and how do i fix this problem?
2.I suspect the roughness from the BSDF principle can't bake the Image texture. The Image texture has to be baked from the colorramp link with BSDF Principle , Am I right?

Pic 1 : node before bake roughness and after bake, I link image texture with roughness replace ColorRamp in this picture and export fbx file.

[image]

Pic 2: Pic in blender

[image]

Pic 3 : Pic in 3d view

[image]

Comment: You can't export the shader graph to FBX. If you plug image textures to the shader's sockets a few of them will be exported, but nothing will be baked. So if you want to export the material, you have to plug only textures to the shader node. So bake and save (and match) everything before export.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right. You mean bake roughness texture and linking the image texture to the roughness socket? if yes i have done it but its not showing on fbx. If not, please guide me as I have been trying to find an answer to this for the past 2 days.

Comment: Did you try to pack the textures into it? FBX exporter window>> Path Mode>> Copy https://youtu.be/kEP34CbPWUo

Comment: I've done it, but the roughness doesn't appear. So I decided to install unity to test if there are any issues. And Roughness is not a problem but I still don't understand why the 3D view doesn't show. Answering your question makes me feel good and keep trying with it, Thank you very much.